# Second quantisation representation of one particle operator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, second-quantization

Is there any consistent way to prove the form of the one particle operator in second quantisation representation on a general basis, i.e $$\hat T=\sum_{ij}T_{ij}\hat a^\dagger_i\hat a_j$$ where $\hat a^\dagger,\hat a$ are the particle creation and annihilation operators. Specifically, I am asking if it is possible to do so without Ansatz, just by explicitly deriving its form from its first quantisation representation, i.e $$\hat T=\sum_{ij}T_{ij}|{\Psi_i}\rangle\langle\Psi_j|$$
by using all available notions and definitions one has already introduced together with the Fock rep. and the annihilation and creation operators (their action on the empty state, their (anti)commutation relations etc.).

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) Did you attempt to prove it yourself?

Comment: Yes, I've only tried the following thought, that $\hat T=\sum_{ij}T_{ij}\hat a^\dagger_i|0\rangle\langle 0|\hat a_j$ and then acting this thing on $\hat a^\dagger_1...\hat a^\dagger_N|0\rangle$, but I cannot make any further sense of it, because this thing should give a $\delta_{jk}$ for an $\hat a^\dagger_k$ amongst these or something?